# JVM memory cleaned up without any GC activity

Tags: java, groovy, garbage-collection, permgen

I am currently running a long running JVM application (that includes groovy classes), and I have observed some strange behaviour.

I run the application and update my Groovy classes (correctly cleaning up metaclass info etc - I know there isn't a leak) so I know there are several classes that could be collected from permgen (normally I observe that permgen isn't collected eagerly - i believe it is just full GC that collects permgen, so not unusual for this state). The oddity is that if I leave the application running with no activity, after about an hour or so there is a sudden drop in memory usage (heap and permgen, but most pronounced in permgen), but visualvm reports no GC/CPU activity has happened.

Below is the screenshot of my visualvm logging

[image]

My question is how is there such a big drop (~80mb) in permgen with no registered GC activity? visualvm does normally log GC/CPU activity pretty well.

Comment: Do you have any gc logs for that time? Do they show anything happening?

Comment: Don't have any logs beyond the basic chart - the top left graph plots CPU/GC activity, and as you can see, there is no activity corresponding to the large drop in permgen usage (top right) - I will look more into the gc logs, but visualvm usually plots GC/CPU pretty accurately the rest of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install visualgc plugin, to investigate how gc work in this situation. I guess a lot of  new generation object was dropped, but I can't told it by screenshot.

Comment: It is permgen being dropped (graph top right of the image is permgen) - so not new generation. The question was more about how ~80mb of permgen was collected with no GC activity being logged (top left graph in image).

Comment: How can I reproduce this?

Comment: Easiest way is to repeatedly load classes but then release them so they are free for GC (e.g. using Groovy, create classloaders, load up classes then throw away classloaders). If you do this whilst monitoring GC you will likely see that permgen is only collected during Full-GC so permgen might get pretty full of classes that could be collected.  I just then left the application running (no new classes being loaded) and then some time later (normally around 1hr more or less) it just dropped.